# combo box access level

Tags: c#, variables, combobox

I am making a POS system, and doing an employee log, which allows you to set all the information of any employee working in the store.  I want to set a combo box that read the following numbers: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` - this is the access level to different parts of the program.

How do I make it so that when 1 is selected, the employee access level variable turns to 1?

```
 public employee_info()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int num;

        try
        {
            num = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);  
            label1.Text = num.ToString();
        }

        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            label5.Text = "please enter only number";
        }
    }

    private void employee_info_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = textBox1.Text;
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        String emial = textBox3.Text;

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

this is a pop up screen where you add all of the employee info , its simple , the only 2 thing that i am missing is the combo box selection for the access level and the other that not so important is to add this  info on a list box , but only the name of the employee appears but as soon as you click on it  the same pop appears and you can see or edit the informacion, this is my first "real project" so far for college

Comment: Could you post some code? And it is not really that clear to me what your problem is?

Comment: i have posted some of the code so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to get the value from the combobox, maybe this will help:

```
String item = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
int value = int.Parse(item);
employeeAccessLevel = value;
```

You may want to use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx), or implement some error handling as well.

---

Or if you are trying to figure out how to update *when the selection changes*, try looking into the [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)